# Building an activity and notification stream for a social network application

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq, real-time, message-queue

As the title suggests, currently my social network backend is in NodeJs with MongoDB and I am looking to add celery + RabbitMQ with Postgres/Cassandra for the activity feed/notification as message queue on fanout based. Do I am approaching my problem in the correct way or do I have to look for something like Kafka or else?
I am also in mixed of doubts where does my broker should be like my backend serves REST API for different clients.

Suppose an app which has a Home feed which updates as someone posts some post. As posts are persisted in any Database, how they are queued or added to the message broker for an app to consume and how they can perform more operation on that post(the post has likes shares and comments feature).

**Need some insight on the way to approach real-time feed problem like the way of Facebook, Instagram or Reddit, etc**

Comment: Your choice of the MQ would depend on the detailed requirements which would require you to think through more details. The last question needs to be rephrased so that it could be well understood

Comment: @AndyDufresne yes that's the question are and I have so many doubts about how to approach for a solution. Also, I updated my last question.